# (THREE.js) Software Renderer not rendering my scene in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, three.js, webgl

I am trying to render some 3d graphics in Node.js land. After tons of googling, I found the Software Renderer and got it running, however I have problem with rendering my scene.

The problem is that my 3d objects simply don't show up on the generated image. I tried inserting Planes, Spheres, GridHelpers, without any luck - nothing shows up really. IF I change the background color using `renderer.setClearColor( )`, however, I can see the new solid color applied to the image

I tested the code in browser using `THREE.WebGLRenderer` and it works fine, the problem is not with the camera positioning / etc...

Here is my renderer code. You can see in the renderFrame method how I am rendering my `THREE.Scene` and then writing the data to a new png, which I am serving:

```
const THREE = require('three');
const SoftwareRenderer = require('three-software-renderer');
const PNG = require('pngjs').PNG;

let width  = 1024;
let height = 768;

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, width / height, 1, 1000);
const renderer = new SoftwareRenderer({
    alpha: false
});
renderer.setSize(width, height);

camera.position.set(0, 600, 500);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);

const box = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.BoxGeometry(20, 20, 20),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xFFFF00 })
);
scene.add(box);

const renderFrame = (pos) => {

    camera.position.set(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);

    let imageData = renderer.render(scene, camera);

    let png = new PNG({
        width: width,
        height: height,
        filterType: -1
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < imageData.data.length; i += 1) {
        png.data[i] = imageData.data[i];
    }

    return png;

}
```

And here is my Express app handling the request:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const renderer = require('./app/renderer/renderer');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 1201;

app.use(express.static('app'));

app.route('/').get((req, res) => {
    let renderExport = renderer.renderFrame({
        x: 40, y: 40, z: 30
    });
    //res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'image/png' });
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/png');
    renderExport.pack().pipe(res); 
});

app.listen(PORT, () => { console.log(`App is listening on ${PORT}`) });
```

I have been banging my head against the keyboard for a few hours now, any help is more then appreciated...

Comment: have you tried to add a light or ambientlight?

Answer (score 0):

This looks fishy: `camera.lookAt(scene.position);`. According to the docs `Scene` doesn't have a `position` property. If that's `undefined` then that would explain why your code doesn't work. It might well be that an undefined look-at is interpreted differently by WebGLRenderer and SoftwareRenderer.

Try setting the look-at to some explicit value, like (0,0,0).